# HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path with solr

Tags: solr, jetty, http-status-code-404

I am new to Solr. After installing it in ubuntu 8.10, when I was following the example to index as per this [link](http://geekblog.vodpod.com/2009/03/09/using-solr-lucene-for-search-with-ruby-on-rails/), I got this error in Jetty:

> HTTP ERROR: 404  missing core name in path

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 19):

I had gotten the same error:

> HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in
> path

In my case, I forgot to set the `solr/home` value in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

```xml
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

After I added the above code and restarted the server, the error was gone.

Comment: Incidentally, if the solr/home is empty (i.e. if you forgot to put the solr.xml and conf/* files there) you can also get this error message.

Comment: Also, remember to uncomment the <env-entry> block.

Answer (score 11):

You probably have a [multi-core setup](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#Configuration) and haven't included the core in the URL. e.g. instead of  requesting `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*` you have to request `http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCoreName/select/?q=*%3A*`

Comment: Hi Mauricio Scheffer,
sorry for late response.
How do i find out whether i have multicore setup or not?

Is this something to do with multicore folder.

when i tried http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/  

I got this again HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path

Comment: See if you have a solr.xml file in your solr.home. It will have a line like `<core name="MyCoreName" instanceDir="core0" />`

Comment: yes,i found it.thank you;
Actually i am trying dataimport as in
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#datasource(uses hsqldb) 
But my database is mysql ,
In db-dat-config.xml i have to use
datasource  url="jdbc:mysql:./example-DIH/mysql/ex
 how do i get ex files as in hsqldb?

when i used http://localhost:8983/solr/
am getting http 500  
Severe errors in solr configuration 
 Is this because of mysql/ex ?

Comment: I have no idea but that's another question altogether. Please include the whole error message in the new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you just browse to http://localhost:8983/solr/ you will see all cores listed (at least that did it for me).

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep a note here, if you deleted all files from your solr/data/index directory but left the directory alone and started getting this error, then stop solr, delete the solr/data/index directory and restart. Solr will create the index directory again. For some reason solr will give you this error if it finds the index directory but not the initial stuff it expects in there.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Been tearing my hair out for a week solid trying to get it to work. Thanks so much for posting this.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was happening due to a previous installation of Solr. So I had to delete my old core directory:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/solr/mycorename
```

then recreate the directory with correct permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/solr/mycorename/data
sudo chown -R jetty:jetty /var/lib/solr/mycorename/data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not use SolrCores, but:

After installing new solr version, I got error "HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path"
And `http://xxx:8080/solr-tour/admin/cores` was empty. (If you don't use solrCore, 1 entry is here normally)

I must stop tomcat, delete his localfiles, and start again

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat5 stop
rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat5/work/Catalina/localhost/*
rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat5/webapps/*
rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat5/logs/*
/etc/init.d/tomcat5 start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening due to versioning.

Earlier I was using solr 1.4.1. It was running fine. Then I installed solr 3.6.1 and was getting this error.

A folder named solr is there in the `tomcat/webapps` directory where you generally put the *solr.war* file.

- Delete this solr folder
- Start tomcat

=> Problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was deeper, as I had not set up Solr correctly to begin with.

I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall

Basically, apart from just unzipping the `solr.war` war file to the webapps directory, you need to create a solr home directory (for which you can copy example/solr in the distribution you downloaded).

Then, as per happy-coding's suggestion, you can configure the web.xml file to point to this directory. Restart (if necessary), and voila!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in *Tomcat Installed Dir*\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml

```xml
<Context docBase="C\:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\solr" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="D:\\workspace\\common\\src\\test\\resources\\solr\\cores" override="true" />
</Context>
```

The cores folder path was wrong for me, as I moved the workspace from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've got exactly this error when my solrconfig.xml was malformed (missing closing tag element ).
It was for solr 3.5.0
Once I fixed the solrconfig the error went away.