# Configuring Solr running on Tomcat & Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, solr

I'm new to Solr, and am having trouble getting my setup to work.  I'm using Solr 3.5.0 running on Tomcat 7.0.23, on Windows 7 Professional.  If I copy the single core example into my Solr home, it doesn't work - I get 404 errors from Tomcat for both http://foo/solr/admin/ and http://foo/solr/collection1/admin/.  I've tried to convert the multicore example (which works, probably because solrconfig.xml is a lot simpler) to use a single core by deleting the additional folder and changing solr.xml to this:

```
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="core0">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

As I understand it, this should mean that I can access core0 using either http://localhost/solr/admin/ or http://localhost/solr/core0/admin/, but only the second URL works - the other just returns a 404 stating "missing core name in path".  I thought that `defaultCoreName` meant I didn't need to specify the core name in the path.  Should the `defaultCoreName` attribute work the way I expected it to, and if so please could you suggest areas of the configuration that I ought to have a look at in order to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path with solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you expect is correct. http://localhost/solr/admin/ should give the same result as [http://localhost/solr/core0/admin/](http://localhost/solr/cor0/admin/)

Not sure what the problem is, are you running Tomcat on port 80 instead of 8080?

Comment: I'm running on 8080.  I followed the Windows setup instructions from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat, so can't figure out what I've missed.  I guess the issue could be connected with the single core example not running, but as I'm not familiar with Tomcat I don't really know where it would log errors - can't see any in either the manager app or the event viewer.

Comment: Turned out to be some form of installation error - albeit a cunningly masked one where Tomcat was 99% working.  Uninstalling then reinstalling with all options selected seems to have fixed the issue.