# Solr/admin gives 404 error

Tags: tomcat, solr

I want to install Solr on my Windows 7 64bit machine. No matter what I do, I get a 404 when I go to Solr/admin.

However `http://localhost:8080/solr/` works and I get "Welcome to Solr".

- I have also entered the path to Solr home in the Web.xml file.
- I followed this [HERE](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Tomcat_on_Windows).
- Tom cat is version 7 and Solr is 3.5

The error:

> HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path
>
> type Status report
>
> message missing core name in path
>
> description The requested resource (missing core name in path) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.23

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr

Comment: None of those solutions fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I switched to solr 3.4 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

copy solr.xml, core0 and core1 direcotories from ../examples/multicore/ to soloar home directory

Answer (score 0):

You are running multi core installation.
Instead of

`http://localhost:8080/solr/`

Visit:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/core0`

Comment: That didn't work. I got a 404 again. Nothing works besides /solr/

Comment: Can you post your solr xml config. You most likely then do not have the request handler set up.

Comment: Well I didn't change it. It is the default version. I just followed the tutorial provided by apache

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you won't post your config then we can't help you. It might be the default, but you realise that "default" comes in many forms.  Depening on which version, you are supplied with at least *three* defaults.

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is a "/" at the end of the url. just going to /admin causes a similar error.